# Is it possible to host a javascript browser extension on IBM Bluemix, and if so how?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ibm-cloud, browser-extension

I have a generic javascript browser extension which connects to an IBM Cloudant instance.
Is it possible to host this extension on IBM Bluemix and if so, how does this work?

Comment: Do you mean to make available a single file for download or do you mean a website where the extension is offered? Yes and yes.

Comment: I mean the server part of an extension. The extension (plugin) will be made available on the specific web stores. The extension connects to the server part which I want to host on IBM Bluemix.